# Displaying meta description containing character entity's

Tags: php

I'm using the `get_meta_tags` function to display the description field of a website which a user has posted.

It works fine but the problem is when the description field contains entity's such as comma's or apostrophes and htmlspecialchars converts them to & #44;or & apos;etc.

I fully understand that this is the expected output, but my question is can I escape output and still display the escaped characters correctly.

Code:

```
$url = 'http://ebay.com'; // User inputted

$meta_tag = !empty(get_meta_tags($url)['description'] );
$description = $meta_tag ? get_meta_tags($url)['description'] : 'Not Available';

echo htmlspecialchars($description);
```

The above code will generate the string:
Buy and sell electronics, cars, fashion apparel, collectibles, sporting goods, digital cameras, baby items, coupons, and everything else on eBay, the world& apos;s online marketplace.

But I want to display: Buy and sell electronics, cars, fashion apparel, collectibles, sporting goods, digital cameras, baby items, coupons, and everything else on eBay, the world's online marketplace.

As the description meta tag could be changed it's user input, and so obviously needs to be escaped, but how can I display it correctly??

Comment: Just remove `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Wouldn't that be a security issue though?? Somebody could change the meta description of a website to something malicious.

Comment: In this case, I don't think so. But if you're really worried about security you can wrap `<pre></pre>` tags around `$description`. `
echo "<pre>".$description."</pre>";`